# Show recurrence $T(n)=2*T(n-2)+3$ satisfy $T(n)=O(2^{n/10})$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Well the original question was asking about Tower of Hanoi.
First I need to come up with a recurrence for the Tower of Hanoi with 4 poles. (Please note the original tower only consist of 3 poles)

The recurrence I came up with is $T(n)=2*T(n-2)+3$

Then part b of the question ask me to show that the recurrence I came up with satisfy $T(n)=O(2^{n/10})$. Doesn't have a clue how to show this.

Comment: Eyeballing it; your recurrence grows faster than $ O (2 {n/10}) $.

Comment: I end up with the same conclusion, after calculations done. There must be a problem with the recurrence @Benjamin :)

Comment: @Benjamin Did you figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this recurrence and the Hanoi tower, but an easy way to solve it is using difference equations:
$$
T_{n-1} = 2 T_{n-3} + 3
$$
Now subtract this equation from the one in your question and denote $\Delta T_n = T_n - T_{n-1}$ and work your way to $\Delta T_1$. Then sum over $n$ and on LHS you'll have most terms cancelling out. Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to seperate each case n odd, n even.

If n is even, define: $ U_p = T_{2p} = T_n $

You get : $ U_p = 2U_{p-1} + 3 $

Dividing by $2^p$ and setting $V_p = \frac{U_p}{2^p}$ you get:

$ V_p = V_{p-1} + \frac{3}{2^p} $

Telescoping the $V_p$ you get :

$ V_p -V_o = 3\sum_{k=1}^p \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^p}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 3(1-2^{-p}) $

You end up with : $T_{2p} = U_p =2^p*V_p = 3(2^p-1) +2^p*T_o$

From here it's not very difficult. You can do the same defining $U_p = T_{2p+1}$ when n is odd, n=2p+1

Comment: However here you get $T_n = O(2^{\frac{n}{2}})$, I'm not sure about the recurrence relation, only about my calculus :) .

You can't be sure that $T_n = O(2^{\frac{n}{10}})$, since $2^{\frac{n}{10}} < 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$. In fact you can even prove that it's false, since $T_n$ contains terms like $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ and the ratio between this and $2^{\frac{n}{10}} \rightarrow +\infty$